# E-mail de Aviso/Report

Tags: php, html, css

Olá! Sou iniciante e estou praticando, porém PHP não sei quase nd. Estou querendo criar um tipo de aviso por e-mail. Contendo o título, número do capítulo e o conteúdo escolhido pelo select. Tentei fazer pelo envio de e-mai normal, mas não consegui.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Tahoma";
}

.reporte {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10001;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -230px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

.campo h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #a42f2f;
}

select, input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    outline: 0;
}

label {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888888;
}

select, input {
    border: none;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

select {
    color: #888888;
}

#btn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #a42f2f;
    color: #a42f2f;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#btn:hover {
    background-color: #a42f2f;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#opacidade {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="reporte">
        <div class="campo">

            <h2>Informe o Erro</h2>
            <form action="" method="post">

                <select name="opcoes" required>
  <option value="1">Sem páginas</option>
  <option value="2">Capítulo repetido</option>
  <option value="3">Páginas embaralhadas</option>
  <option value="4">Falta página</option>
  <option value="5">Páginas repetidas</option>
</select></br>
                <label for="titulo2">Digite o nome:</label></br>
                <input type="text" name="titulo2" id="titulo2" placeholder="Título..." required></br>

                <label for="capitulo2">Digite o número:</label></br>
                <input type="text" name="capitulo2" id="capitulo2" placeholder="01..." required></br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btn">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="opacidade"></div>
```

Comment: Você disse que tentou fazer, mas cadê o código que você tentou? Venha também [mcve].

Comment: Então Francisco, eu tentei com esse código aqui:  https://www.kinghost.com.br/wiki/artigo/formphp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `mail()`:

```
<?php
$opt = $_POST['opcoes'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo2'];
$cap = $_POST['capitulo2'];

//Pessoa que vai receber o email
$destinatario = "joaonegao@gmail.com";

//Assunto do email
$assunto = "Sobre o erro: $opcoes";

//Corpo do email
$mensagem =
"
Referente ao erro: $opcoes
Titulo: $titulo
Capitulo: $cap
";

//Envio do email
mail($destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, "From: joaolegal@gmail.com"."\r\n"."CC: pedrinmatagal@gmail.com");
?>
```

Não se esqueça de configurar o `php.ini`!

Veja [isso](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp), se se tiver mais duvidas. Ou a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).

Comment: Francisco, funcionou mt obrigado. Mas teve um erro... toda hora q eu dou f5 na página ele reenvia.

Comment: Isso não é um erro, está certo. O que você deve fazer é não deixar isto acontecer por meio de algum `if`.

Comment: Consegui. Criei um If pra se enviar em branco n enviar, porém quando dou f5 depois de enviar um. Ele reenvia.

Comment: Coloque essa condição no seu `if`: `if(isset($_POST['opcoes']))`

Comment: Não se esqueça de dar seu upvote e marcar a resposta como correta!